# Lit element in IE11, css style outside custom element affects style inside

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, lit-element

Setting css styles for a p element in my application is affecting the p element inside a lit-element in IE11 only.

I have setup a very basic [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-css) example to show the issue. When you open this in IE11 you will notice the custom element p text is italic, that style is coming from outside. In other browsers, this does not happen.

Is this a known issue and can't be prevented for IE11? Or is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the problem on my side, it can be possible that it is the IE browser default behavior. Because the outside CSS style is global style.

As a workaround, you could change your selectors to stop them matching the elements you don't want them to match. Such as the [following sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-css-zvydvc?file=index.html) (using a class selector to add CSS style):

Code in the index.html page:

```
  <style>
    .outer-p { font-style: italic; }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <p class="outer-p">Text outside element</p>
    <my-element></my-element>
  </body>
```

Code in the custom element (my-element.js)

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      .inner-p { display:block; font-weight: 900; color: #ff9900; }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <p class="inner-p">Hello world! From my-element</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to avoid this kind of solution, but at the end of the day, it might be the only way.

Comment: This is expected. The `ShadyCSS` polyfill will  namespace CSS to help prevent it from leaking out but it can't do anything to prevent global CSS from leaking in.